# How can I get retweets on a tweet using tweetsharp using tweetID

Tags: tweetsharp

I am currently using TweetSharp to pull in my public timeline to my web application.

Everything is working except I don't seem to be getting any retweets that I post.

Is there a way that I can get my retweets also?

Below is a snip of the code that I am currently using to pull in my tweets.

Comment: RetweetsOptions retweets = new RetweetsOptions();//  r
            retweets.Id = 565498192171507712;
            IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> retweetslist = twitterService.Retweets(retweets);

Comment: You should edit your question and put the code in there, it's not readable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using TweetSharp

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(AccessToken, TokenSecret);
var retweetsForeachPost = service.Retweets(new RetweetsOptions { Count = 150, Id = tweetID});
```

Comment: Format properly and explain your answer please.

Comment: I made the edit. Once you get your tweets, you can use Retweets() to get all the retweets for that tweet by using the tweet ID. Very simple

Answer (score 0):

```
 public TwitterService oTwitterService = null;
 private void RetweetCmnts(TwitterStatus twitterStatus , TwitterResponse response) {
      TwitterStatues = new TwitterStatus();
      TwitterStatues = twitterStatus;
      }
    case TwitterOptions.ReTweet: {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oTimeLineData.UserId) && oTimeLineData.UserId.Length > 0) {
                  TwitterStatus ost = new TwitterStatus();
                  RetweetOptions retweetOptions = new RetweetOptions { Id = Convert.ToInt64(oTimeLineData.Id) , TrimUser = true };
                  Action<TwitterStatus , TwitterResponse> action = RetweetCmnts;
                  action(new TwitterStatus() { Id = Convert.ToInt64(oTimeLineData.Id) , Text = oTimeLineData.TweetedText , InReplyToScreenName = oTimeLineData.ScreenName , InReplyToUserId = Convert.ToInt64(oTimeLineData.UserId) } , null);
                  oTwitterService.Retweet(retweetOptions);
                  if(oTwitterService.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    _wasSuccessfull = true;
                  else {
                    _twitterError = new TwitterError();
                    TwitterResponeError = GetTwitterErrors(_twitterError , "ReTweet");
                    }
                  }
                break;
                }
```

Comment: 1. Get Twitter Service activated using client id , client secret , token id and token secret